# Mod_Rewrite with parameters - Dynamic Website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change my URLS.
At the moment they look like this:

```
http://website.net/?page=news
http://website.net/?page=information&skin=217 (shows a  mario skin with informations)
```

I want them to look like this:

```
http://website.net/news/
http://website.net/mario/
```

What I have tried so far is following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=information&skin=217$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/$
RewriteRule .* http://website.net/Mario/? [R=301,L]
```

^ This Code works for changing the URL-Addresse, but I get a 404 Error: Page not found. Seems like this isnt working too well.

What did I miss and what do I have to change?
This also has to work with given parameters so: http://website.net/Mario/ should still know the parameters page=information, skin=217

Thanks

Comment: ?page= is url. Content gets included in index.php by $_GET['page']

Comment: Sorry, saw my mistake. Changed to ?page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?page=information&skin=217\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /mario/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?page=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^mario/?$ /?page=information&skin=217 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Works thanks so far, but my CSS doesnt work now. I think I have to change my paths in index.php right?

Comment: For css/js relative paths, add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Quick Question, what if my url is like this: `?page=information&skin=superman` and I want to automaticly change it to `website.net/superman/`. So that the url is what skins parameter is like. Because I have a lot of skins and it would take forever to change it manually. That would be great

Comment: It can be redirected to `/superman/` but then last rule will rewrite to `/?page=superman` which is not correct. May be you can redirect to `/information/superman/`

Answer (score 0):

```
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?page=information&skin=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /?page=information&skin=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?page=information&resourcepack=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /?page=information&resourcepack=$1 [L,QSA]`
```

I have this now, works fine with all skins, but doesnt work for resourcepacks. Why?
Also tried to change %1 and $1 in the second blog to %2 and $2.